# File name for uploaded file

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I am using [Valum](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) file uploader library. It works fine for me but I need to provide file name with other parameters. For now I am doing the following:

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: button,
            allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'],
            sizeLimit: 2147483647, // max size
            action: '/ControllerNAme/Action',
            multiple: false,
            params: {PostData: GetFileUploadData()},
            onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
            //My reload logic here.
            },
        });

function GetFileUploadData() {
        var lFileUploadData = new Object();

        //File note is the id of input with type text, in which I type some notes to file
        lFileUploadData.FileNote = $('#FileNote').val(); 

        return JSON.stringify(lFileUploadData);
    };
```

But all the time I have this field empty.

Comment: This plugin passes the file name inside the request anyway. The post var is called qqfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `onchange` event to get file name, maybe, `GetFileUploadData()` function gets the filename on time the file input have not yet been browser to file.

I guess when the following statement initialize at the beginning (means: onload)

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: button,
            allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'],
            sizeLimit: 2147483647, // max size
            action: '/ControllerNAme/Action',
            multiple: false,
            params: {PostData: GetFileUploadData()},
            onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
            //My reload logic here.
            },
        });
```

then:
`$('#FileNote').val()` is empty when you call `GetFifleUploadData()`

So, can you try this one:

```
$("#FileNote").change(function(){
    uploader._options.params.PostData = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Can you, plese, write in more details what even of what object should I use? onchange of what? I know that the problem is that it gets empty FileNote when I didn`t write it there and use it all the time.

Comment: That`s what I`m doing. I know it`s not working, what should I use to make it work?

Comment: Yes, vietean, you are right about this. I know it is the problem, but how to fix it?

Comment: Can you try this one:
`$("#FileNote").change(function(){
 uploader._options.params.PostData = $(this).val();
});`

Comment: @Yaroslav Yakovlev: I am back, it's just a quite quick solution, you can use `extend` method, to override any options in `qq` object. Or, you can pass `params` with a `global` object, using object it will be a reference variable... so it can be change from others function. I meant, _options is private var, so my solution is not good. :)

Comment: Can you, please, post how extend should be used to extend qq object? I can post it in a separate question, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The uploaded file is specified by the `fileName` parameter of the `onComplete` function, called when the upload is done.
You can then pass this value to the server (if needed).
The `params:` section is for parameters sent as POST params, sent to the upload hander URL (specified in `action:` section)